# ADF v2 : Create a multi hierarchy json output using ADF

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I have multiple salesforce objects to use a source to create a json output and store it to the blob,- for example SF objects are Program, project, items, Account and contact

and relationship is like

- 1 program can have multiple projects associated with it.
- 1 program can have multiple accounts associated with it.
- 1 Account can have multiple projects associated with it but one project is associated with 1 account.
- 1 project can have multiple items and
- 1 account can have multiple contacts.

using above salesforce objects json output is something like

```
{
  "programs" : {
    "progam" :[
      {
        "id" :"1",
        "name" : "p1",
        "accounts" :{
          "account" : [
            {
              "aid" : "a1",
              "aname" : "aname",
              "contacts" :{
                "contact" : [
                  {
                    "cnid" : "cn1",
                    "cnnumber": "12334"
                  },
                  {
                    "cnid" : "cn2",
                    "cnnumber": "12334"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "aid" : "a2",
              "aname" : "aname2",
              "contacts" :{
                "contact" : [
                  {
                    "cnid" : "cn12",
                    "cnnumber": "212334"
                  },
                  {
                    "cnid" : "cn22",
                    "cnnumber": "212334"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "projects" : {
          "project" : [
            {
              "projId" : "p1",
              "projname" :"pname1",
              "measures":{
                "measure" : [
                  {
                    "prorefid" : "p1",
                    "measureid": "m1",
                    "measure" : "mm1"
                  },
                   {
                    "prorefid" : "p1",
                    "measureid": "m12",
                    "measure" : "mm12"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "projId" : "p2",
              "projname" :"pname1",
              "measures":{
                "measure" : [
                  {
                    "prorefid" : "p2",
                    "measureid": "m1",
                    "measure" : "mm1"
                  },
                   {
                    "prorefid" : "p2",
                    "measureid": "m12",
                    "measure" : "mm12"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
         {
        "id" :"2",
        "name" : "p2",
        "accounts" :{
          "account" : [
            {
              "aid" : "a21",
              "aname" : "2aname",
              "contacts" :{
                "contact" : [
                  {
                    "cnid" : "cn21",
                    "cnnumber": "212334"
                  },
                  {
                    "cnid" : "cn22",
                    "cnnumber": "212334"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "aid" : "a22",
              "aname" : "aname22",
              "contacts" :{
                "contact" : [
                  {
                    "cnid" : "cn122",
                    "cnnumber": "2212334"
                  },
                  {
                    "cnid" : "cn222",
                    "cnnumber": "2212334"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "projects" : {
          "project" : [
            {
              "projId" : "p12",
              "projname" :"pname12",
              "measures":{
                "measure" : [
                  {
                    "prorefid" : "p12",
                    "measureid": "m12",
                    "measure" : "mm12"
                  },
                   {
                    "prorefid" : "p12",
                    "measureid": "m12",
                    "measure" : "mm12"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "projId" : "p22",
              "projname" :"pname1",
              "measures":{
                "measure" : [
                  {
                    "prorefid" : "p22",
                    "measureid": "m12",
                    "measure" : "mm1"
                  },
                   {
                    "prorefid" : "p22",
                    "measureid": "m122",
                    "measure" : "mm12"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

}

if it has 2 level of hierarchy i would have use copy activity to store data into intermediate storage and then data flow to join and then group by to generate Json output, but its having a multi hierarchy and I don't have any idea to work upon it.

is their any proper way to do so.. thanks!

Comment: Can you provide what is your expected output from the above input?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula Json example I given is the expected output json file

Comment: Could you share the input data?

Comment: @Aswin right now i just got a POC work and all i got info is 5 salesforce object and relationship between them which i shared in query. on that assumption i created that demo output

Answer (score 0):

To generate the JSON output from multiple Salesforce objects with complex relationships, you can use Azure Data Factory with a combination of Copy Activity and Data Flow. Below is the overview,

- Use the Salesforce Source connector in Copy Activity to extract data from the Salesforce objects you need and copy those objects to azure blob storage/ data lake storage gen2. This is done because, we cannot use salesforce object as a source in dataflow.
- Use Data Flow to transform the blob storage data into the desired JSON format. Use `Join transformation` to join all the objects into single table.
- After joining the data, use `Aggregate transformation` to group the data by the required fields.
- Use the `Sink transformation` in the Data Flow to write the JSON output to Blob storage.

**Join transformation:**

- Refer the Microsoft document on [Join transformation in mapping data flow - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join) and join all the tables based on their relationship.

**Aggregate Transformation:**

- Refer the [Microsoft community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/how-to-convert-csv-file-into-array-of-jsons-in-adf/ba-p/3574859)
  page which describes how to convert the CSV to array of Json. You can use this to convert the Join transformation output to the required Json file.

Comment: Hi Aswin, right! I'm doing same, first i did copy all SF object data to separate csv files in blob and then using data flow trying to do join and then aggregate collect expression i do facing some json invalid issue, but will try to solve it